# Getting a list of REST resources from Slim

Tags: php, slim

I'm using the PHP Slim Framework for my RESTful project.

I was wondering if its possible to get a list of all the callback registered with Slim somehow so as to have a list of all the REST resources that are available for the app?

I assume this will involve some sort of pre-compile but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the Slim Framework yet (looks quite exciting, thanks for the pointer), but my best guess would be using PHPDocumentor to generate documentation about your rest endpoints.

You can find it at [the phpdocumentor website](http://www.phpdoc.org/)